# How to custom static style UITableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

There's already built a Static Tableview with Storyboard. How to custom its appearance, like changing cells' background.

(I could write a tableview with code, but I just want to make use of the advantage of storyboard. For static tableView, its much more convenient.)

Comment: Hi,you can put a custom cell on your table view give it's identifier use it.Give custom class to your Custom cell.After that you can use that cell same as xib.

Comment: It's a tableview that have Static Cells, which means there are more than one cells in the tableview, and the cell is not a prototype one. I can't use its identifier in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: